# Actionscript . I can't use text background in textarea

Tags: actionscript-3, textarea

I want to create a small chatbox for my site. But I can't use text background in a textarea.
I don't know if I should use textarea or something else. Some users can use background color on their own text. I tried the .background command with textarea but I think it does not support it.

example: [link](http://s15.postimage.org/b127u8y9n/as3.jpg) ( I want this)
How can I make this ?

Comment: have you first set the background property of your text field to true?

Comment: Are you using Flex, or is it plain AS3?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Text Highlighter](http://blog.formatlos.de/2009/06/22/as3-texthighlighter/).